# Why is the following code returning 0 yet the variable cash should be updated?

Tags: kotlin, lambda

I have made sure that the list aren't null. They have values that prints in logcat yet the cash variable isn't updated.

```
var cash = 0
val intent = intent
group = intent.getParcelableExtra("group")
viewModel.getBank(group).observe(this, Observer {

        for (i in it) {

            Log.d("DashBoard", "Bank Amount ${i.bank_amount}")
            cash += i.bank_amount!!.toInt()
        }

})
viewModel.getMpesa(group).observe(this, Observer {

        for (i in it) {
            Log.d("DashBoard", "Mpesa Amount ${i.mpesa_amount}")
            cash += i.mpesa_amount!!.toInt()
        }

})

binding.textViewCash.text = cash.toString()
```

Comment: If the getBank() method was able to return the data it gets directly, it would return it. But it doesn't. instead, it forces you to pass an observer as argument, and passes the data it gets to the observer, later, **asynchronously**. See it as an email: if you send an amail, you can't read the answer right away. You can only read the answer once the email client tells you that the response has arrived, asynchronously, a long time later.

Comment: So whats the solution?

Comment: I don't know anything about Android, but **if** the callback is run in the UI thread, then move the `binding.textViewCash.text = cash.toString()` line *inside* the Observer callback.

Comment: Well that only capture one method but I want all both getBank and getMpesa

Comment: Again, I don't know anything about the Android PI, and the way to combine two observers for example, so there might be a much better way to do it. And the proper solution would be to take a huge step back and learn about asynchrony and about this oberver API. But you can read the current value of what the text field has, increment it, and set it to the new value. I.e. if your test field contains 2500 and you receive 3000, set the value to 2500 + 3000 = 5500.

Comment: Thank you but if I do that way I am getting off by one error. It's so frustrating